# How to make query of MySQL connection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, query, database, mysql

i have added a connection with a MySQL database in QGIS
(Add vector layer - Database - MySQL).

Is there an option to make a query over the database in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using the DB Manager of QGIS.

You choose **Database / Database Manager / Database Manager** then **Virtual Layers / Qgis Layers**. At this stage you should be able to see all the tables opened (MySql, Postgre ...)

You can query these tables like any opened table : just click on the "wrench" icon ("**SQL window**") - this open an area in which u can edit your SQL query.

You can then load the result in the layer manager.